# create image and rendering inside canvas issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/phjUL/11/

code:

```
function createShipMissil(x, y,imgw,imgh) {

            missile = new Image();
            missile.onload = function () {
                ctx.drawImage(missile, x + 25, y, imgw,imgh);
                y--; 
            }
            missile.src = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRwk5oUcssd2r4wzBQMBPr9c0BSEjjwpnl5MhoBSJaUV2Dwaxmvu31BMVk';
            setTimeout(function () { createShipMissil(x, y,imgw,imgh); }, 0.5);
        }

        function render() {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);

            if (startgame) {
                DrawStatistics();
               // createShipMissil(px, py,1,15);
            }
            ctx.drawImage(playerimage, px, py, pw, ph);

        }
```

I am facing a problem with rendering the missile when space bar is hit as you will see in the example

Comment: Hm...Funny enough, the setTimeout line is exactly what I'd expect at the bottom of the `render()` method - though with some alterations. What exactly should happen when the user presses spacebar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your core problem is that you do not have any central game loop. This is essential in any game that makes use of "real time" events and interactions. Don't worry however, it is normally the first mistake newbie game makers make. Some of the following may be of interest:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_programming#Game_structure
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/notearsgame/
- http://www.wimagguc.com/projects/jquery-game-loop-and-game-engine/

#### The reason for the issue

Your problem is that when you fire a missile you are creating a time loop for that missile, which does go on to draw your missle continually; however, you are also only clearing your game display when a user presses a key — which means your missle draws as a line. You could get this system working for one missle and one player, but if you start adding more projectiles and enemies you will get into more and more problems. It is far easier to think around, and code, when your game has a singular update "beat" i.e. a game loop — rather than every entity having their own update "beat", which you then have to synchronise.

A great analogy for this is to think of plain old *reality*. In real life, time doesn't just start occuring when something happens (unless you start really getting into [quantum mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics), [spacetime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime) and the big bang!) — instead, time is always passing and new entities/objects are brought into existence that can then interact during that time. Once those objects have been and gone, time still continues (unless you subscribe to any random [observer based theory](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6l5Zh7w9yQ)).

#### The solution

You need to change your perspective with regards to updates/redraws. You need to think in terms of your objects existing in a world and they each get a beat or tick to make a change to their location or display, after that tick, the entire game screen updates... and — usually — you should have at least 24 of these ticks occuring every second (in order to trick the human eye that the static objects drawn on the screen are actually moving).

So, instead of creating a new interval for each of your bullets, you should start off with a singular global interval that controls the entire redraw of your game. There are a few ways to do this, the simplest is to use `setInterval` as you have done in your code, however there are downsides to this method — the more modern way to achieve this is to use `window.requestAnimationFrame`:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame

Then once you have this loop firing 24 times (or more) per second, you can then handle all the entities that are added to you world. This generally means having some kind of centralised lists that keep track of each entity. This is completely up to you, some people will keep only one list i.e. array of entities; others will break that list into more descriptive terms like `bullets`, `players`, `enemies`... and so on. Here is some pseudo code to illustrate how your game loop could look:

```
var display = {/* object that controls your canvas */};
var entities = [];
var entity = {/* object/constructor represents a game entity i.e. player */}

var gameloop = function(){
  display.clear();
  for( var i=0; i<entities.length; i++ ) {
    entities[i].update();
  }
};
```

Obviously with the above there is nothing in `entities`. This is where other code would come in, to prep `entities` to contain your player and some other items already in the world; and futher code that would append and remove entities as the game progresses i.e. bullets, e.g:

```
entities.push( new entity({
  type: 'player',
  image: 'ship.png'
}) );
```

You should design each of your entities to support a method called `update`, so whatever new entity you add, it will automatically be supported by the game loop. This `update` method should be responsible for moving that entity (whatever it is) around the world, and if you wish, drawing the entity in the world — however it is generally best to separate your `update` and `draw` calls so that all entities have finished moving, before redraw occurs — this can help with calculating collisions:

```
var gameloop = function(){
  display.clear();
  for( var i=0; i<entities.length; i++ ) {
    entities[i].update();
  }
  for( var i=0; i<entities.length; i++ ) {
    entities[i].draw();
  }
};
```

#### How to handle keyboard interaction

This is another tricky thing that people normally assume to be easy in HTML-based games, considering you already have key events to listen for. However you should never link your key presses directly to update code... otherwise you get what occurs in your demo, where the "key repeat" firing causes strange motion.

What you should do is listen for the keys, as you are doing, but update a `controls` object (or something similar) with the current state of the key presses. Then in your entity `update` methods you listen for the key states your entity should respond to and perform that action. This dislocates the key press to the action, avoids the key repeat, and means things keep within the "beat" of the game, it also allows you to control the reaction to that key press (or key combinations) more specifically. The following code again is an illustration:

```
var controls = {};

$(document).on(
  'keydown': function(e){
    controls[e.keyCode] = true;
  },
  'keyup': function(e){
    delete controls[e.keyCode];
  }
);
```

Then at the point you wish to checks for a key's state, you could easily use:

```
if ( controls[32] ) {
  /// space has been pressed
}
```

#### Conclusion

So overall I'd recommend reading through a HTML5 game tutorial, see top links, and rework you game into that design. You'll find it much easier to work with.